# How to load navigation properties for all collection items explicitly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Here's sample model classes, which being use with Entity Framework Code First:

```
public class Master
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Collection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Master Master { get; set; }
  public SubDetail SubDetail1 { get; set; }
  public SubDetail SubDetail2 { get; set; }
}

public class SubDetail
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load `Master` with all of its details and sub-details explicitly. To load details I'm using `Include`:

```
context.Masters.Include("Details").Where(master => master.Id == 1);
```

What should I use to load sub-details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
context.Masters.Include(m => m.Details.Select(d => d.SubDetail1))
   .Include(m => m.Details.Select(d => d.SubDetail2))
   .Where(master => master.Id == 1);
```

Non generic version

```
context.Masters.Include("Details.SubDetail1")
   .Include("Details.SubDetail2")
   .Where(master => master.Id == 1);
```

Comment: DbQuery<TEntity> has `Include` method, which receives string path as parameter. Is `Include` from your sample any custom extension-method?

Comment: [`Include<T, TProperty>(IQueryable<T>, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103)) If you are using EF 4.3 you should be able to use it

Comment: @Dennis Added the non generic version to the answer